# Get XElement Value

Tags: c#, xml, string, xelement

I have an `XElement` object which I would like to get its value as string.

However, the `ToString()` method returns the xml tree with /r/n and spaces which I woild like to ignore.

Is there an attribute of `XElement` which retrieves the `XML` tree as string without unnecessary adding?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: @user1929959, it does give a string but not the one I want. I want to get a string which appropriate to the xml tree structure.

Comment: In this use method described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468714%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: To make it a question, add examples of input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass [SaveOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.saveoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as parameter to [ToString method of XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb551415.aspx).

```
var xml = XElement.Parse("<a><b></b><c><d></d></c></a>");

Console.WriteLine(xml.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting));
```

prints:

```
<a><b></b><c><d></d></c></a>
```

While just calling `ToString()` will indeed produce formatted result

```
Console.WriteLine(xml.ToString());
```

prints:

```
<a>
  <b></b>
  <c>
    <d></d>
  </c>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use XElement.InnerXml statement.

Comment: I have no InnerXml as one of the XElement attributes. This attribute is a node's attribute.